# Como trazer uma pagina com gráfico dentro de um div em outra pagina usando ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, canvas

Estou com um problema, tenho uma função simples em Ajax que trás uma página dentro de uma *div*, fiz o teste funcionar, porem quando faço para trazer uma página que tenha gráfico não trás nada,

Alguém sabe se tem uma maneira de se fazer isso?

meu código segue embaixo:

essa é a pagina index.php

**index.php**

```
<?php
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function GetXMLHttp() {
    if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

var xmlRequest = GetXMLHttp();


function abrirPag(valor){
    var url = valor;

    xmlRequest.open("GET",url,true);    
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = mudancaEstado;
    xmlRequest.send(null);

        if (xmlRequest.readyState == 1) {
            document.getElementById("conteudo_mostrar").innerHTML = "<img src='img/load.gif'>";
        }

    return url;
}

function mudancaEstado(){
    if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById("conteudo_mostrar").innerHTML = xmlRequest.responseText;
    }
}
</script>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Carregando Página em DIV / AJAX</title>
<script language="javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="instrucao.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div id="menu"><a href="#" onclick="abrirPag('canvas.php');">Clientes</a></div>
        <input type="submit" value="teste"/>
        <br><br>
    <div id="conteudo_mostrar"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

e esse é o código da página canvas.php que tem o gráfico:

**canvas.php**

```
<?php 

    $codigo = @$_REQUEST['codigo'];


?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
                'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                pointStart: 1940,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'USA',
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104]
        }, {
            name: 'USSR/Russia',
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
                4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
                15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
                33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
                21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
        }]
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Fiz o teste abrindo a página do gráfico direto funciona, mas precisava trazer essa página do gráfico na página index.php dentro de uma div da página index.php.

Alguém sabe uma maneira de fazer isso ou onde estou errando?

Comment: você recebe algum retorno deste request ou dá algum erro?

Comment: não da erro, apenas vem em branco o resultado na div não trás o gráfico

Comment: você esta buscando com ajax... pega esse responseText e joga no console (console.log(xmlRequest.responseText);) e vê se esta retornando mesmo

Comment: Estás a ir buscar uma página inteira com `html`, `head` e `body` via ajax e queres colocar dentro de uma div?! Isso não vai dar... quanto muito podes usar uma iFrame.

Comment: eu pensei no iframe mais precisava mesmo fazer isso em ajax, meio problema não que não trás a pagina, trás o que não trás é o gráfico que é feito na biblioteca canvas js já tentei varias outras bibliotecas de grafico mais não da certo

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer carregar uma página com gráfico. Vamos lembrar que o gráfico é gerado dinamicamente no navegador, o highcharts altera o DOM para isso, então se você carregar uma página sem processar novamente o script que gera o gráfico não vai aparecer nada, a não ser se fosse uma imagem. Depois de carregar a página você vai precisar gerar novamente o gráfico, usando `$('#container').redraw();` ou tendo de setar os dados novamente com `$('#container')..series[0].setData(dados,true);`que irá redesenhar o gráfico.